# Exporting constants which depend on an async response - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, next.js

I am writing a script in my typescript NextJS app to manage all of my environment vars. Depending on the environment (local, staging, etc), these variables can either come from process.env, or from AWS Parameter Store.

My goal is to have a file that exports all my env variables and secrets, after first checking AWS for the appropriate secret (asynchronously), then falling back to process.env if it's not found - something like this:

```
async_pg_host = ssm.getParameter({Name: "Test_Parameter", WithDecryption: true}).promise()
export const PGHOST = async_pg_host.Parameter?.value || process.env.PGHOST || "localhost";
```

I massaged the code above and was able to get PGHOST to have a type of `Promise<aws.SSM.GetParameterResult> | string | undefined`. I was expecting a way to resolve async_pg_host down to a `string | undefined` type before exporting the variable, but I have learned this is not possible in JS.

I was able to bodge this by defining the env vars as non-constants, then updating them based on Amazon's return value, but I would really prefer to keep them constant to prevent in-process tampering.

There must be a cleaner way to go about this, but I can't see it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is a very NextJS 12.0.10+ specific answer.

I was able to solve this. NextJS's config can support async operations with some modifications. If you require imports, you must rename `next.config.js` to `next.config.mjs`. Pseudocode below:

```
// next.config.mjs

import getAsyncSecret from 'another-package'

async function getMyAsyncVariables() {
  let async_value = await getAsyncSecret()
  return {
    VARIABLE: async_value || process.env.VARIABLE || ""
  }
}

export default async () => {
  const envConfig = await getMyAsyncVariables();
  return {
    env: {
      ...envConfig,
    },
    ...nextConfig,
  };
};
```

This has the behavior I was looking for. This will check the remote storage, then fall back to the existing env variables, then fall back to a default. The result will be in the process as an environment variable, because this happens at build time.